# Want to refresh a jsp page after every n sec but the servlet do not provide proper JSON the next time

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp, servlets

I want to refresh a jsp page after n sec which uses JSON object from Servlet. At first request, the data gets loaded and I am using Angular Js for JSON.

The second time when the page gets refresh itself, I am getting an invalid JSON from servlet. I looked upon the servlet and found that it appends the prev result also which makes JSON invalid.

I used `session.invalidate()` at the start of the servlet but it is not helping me.

Please suggest something

I included these in JSP page:

```js
<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://localhost:8090/Dashborad/javaAngularJS").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data.records;
  });
});
</script>
<% response.setIntHeader("Refresh",10);%>
```

And, I included these in my Servlet:

```js
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
  session.invalidate();
  
    
response.setContentType("application/json");
  response.getWriter().write(result);
```

Comment: We need to see more Java code - invalidating the session makes no sense.

Comment: does your time value retrieve from servlet ?

Comment: The problem is when I hit again the servlet it appends the previous response to the new one, so it is producing an in valid JSON object which Angular Js can't take. To make it work again, I had to restart the server to clear the response.

Comment: I think, the problem is with my server, when I moved my code to new machine, it worked. Any reason why I did not able to invalidated the data in previous server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's possible in angular, but in jQuery, it's possible to set an interval. Check `$interval`. Using this, the get/ajax call will happen after a specific interval.
Then you can set a servlet timeout of required time-scale. Coupling up these two, the work can be done I suppose.

Comment: Alan, its possible in JSP and HTML itself. Please see below code.                           <%response.setInitHeader("Refresh", 60);%>, where 60 is in sec.              In html:<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" > . Also, we can use timeout function of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

i hope that i understood you well, if do you want to refresh page after specific time retrieved from servlet then you have to make a timer inside ajax request, do something like that.

```
$.get("myServlet",function(data){
 setInterval(function() {
                  window.location.reload();
                }, data.timeToRefresh);
})
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, the problem here is different. I need to invalidate the data from application server on every refresh.